# Can't Activate Environment // Ubuntu // Conda

Tags: command-line, bash, virtualbox, anaconda, environment

I downloaded Anaconda 3 on Ubuntu VM. The conda command wasn't working so I used this command:
**source ~/.bashrc**
but it didn't work. Then I tried this command:
**export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH**

This made the command conda work and then I created an environment.
While trying to active the environment, I got an error which is show in the image[image]

The screenshot feature also isn't working. It gives me a distorted picture.

What steps should I take to active this environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try `conda init bash` from your terminal. You can swap `bash` if you're using a different shell.

If that doesn't work, your initial idea was on the right track. Add the following to your `~/.bashrc` file, which will be run every time you open a new terminal:

```
export PATH="/anaconda3/bin/:$PATH"
```